# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Reset Group Ownership?

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, chgrp

I have inadvertently changed the group ownership of the root directory on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 ☹️ Is there anyway to roll back the changes or reset the group ownership to out of the box (fresh install)?

I used the recursive option with the chgrp command which has obviously changed all files/folders below root. The command I used was `sudo chgrp -R sambashare /`

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See if the answer works. If not I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works :)

I made files with

```
getfacl -R {dir} >{dir}.facl
```

for system related directories. Downloads:

- var: https://drive.google.com/file/d/155VXpDsfjtrJJ2AYyq_Y_Sj0rjulQXAt/view?usp=sharing
- usr:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jJ9MbWrZtUNiwCWBPChALdrpuGnR15uX/view?usp=sharing
- etc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SG4bwp-Hu5RuE_qB_GGDt5w3eVPXBWKz/view?usp=sharing
- bin: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QpM1kDTfcvW68JX2Dh7GCjDFwHRXIsFo/view?usp=sharing

Use

```
setfacl --restore={dir}.facl
```

to reset them. Warning: Change the bin and var file and replace rinzwind (my username) with your username in the bin and var file before doing this.

If sudo permissions are changed use a live session or grub rescue to do this. A live session will be the easier method if you have one.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I've tried to execute the command but I didn't have acl package. I tried to install acl but I can't execute commands as root (sudo). I get `sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

Comment: Use a live session to do this. That way the settings for sudo will be reset too

Comment: thanks, will try that and get back to you.

Comment: this may seem like a stupid question but do I have to prepend the paths in the files you provided with the mount point of my disk? I'm in a live session and when running the command it's erroring with `No such file or directory` Sorry for the newb questions!

Comment: That could well be :) I never did this myself so it is a bit of guesswork: if you open the files with gedit or notepad++ you can change the filenames to include your mount point. That would solve this if you indeed need that path