# I need help to write a bash script for remove and change the permissions that I gave to my ubuntu 20.10 installation files by mistake

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, 20.10

I need some help to write a specific bash script to fix the permission problems that prevent my ubuntu 20.10 from booting properly. Basically this script should :

1. remove the +x permission from each file that shouldn't has it,for example each *.conf file. I'm sure that there are much more files that shouldn't have it,but at the moment I'm not sure which ones. I'm sure that you know it better than me.
2. import the right permissions from a new and working installation of ubuntu 20.10 to the broken one,for the files which have the same name.

thanks.

Comment: #2 does not require a script, There is a tool for that. But I agree with HappyTux: reinstall is far easier, less error prone, and less time consuming See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317222/ubuntu-server-20-04-reset-group-ownership/1317233?noredirect=1#comment2243327_1317233 on how to do #2. You can reset permissions from the files I added there. You need a live session and need to alter the scripts to point to the mounted partitions

Answer (score 3):

Backup up the data you are concerned about and wipe the system, you have successfully killed it. It will take some effort to get done, many, many times the effort of a re-install. Do the new install and copy over the files wanted from the old. Problem is solved in very little time compared to probably days getting a script figured out, if every getting it correct.

Comment: yeah I know. but I wanted to take the chance to learn something new.

Comment: @Marietto see the comment i made.